# Fragment to Fragment startAcivityForResult is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

First, Sorry about my English writing

i want Intent Camera picture, get result fragment

fragment(A) -> intent(Camera) -> fragment(A)

startActivityForResult not working ... what can i do

this code

```
 public void doTakePhotoAction() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // tempdirectory
    String url = "tmp_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), url));

    Log.e("mImageCaptureUri", mImageCaptureUri.toString());

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
    this.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
    Log.d("ididid", getParentFragment().getId() + "");
    Log.d("ididid", getParentFragment().getTag()+"");
    Log.d("ididid", getActivity()+"");
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("onActivityResult","onActivityResult");
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA: {
            try {
                String temp = mImageCaptureUri.toString();
                temp.replace("file://", "");
                Uri final_uri = Uri.parse(temp);
                Log.e("final_uri", final_uri.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: try with getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

Comment: As suggested by parag do getActivity.startActivityForResult and implement onActivityResult in the parent activity

Comment: Thanks for advise @ParagChauhan but no working

Comment: @bongjaechoe can you paste whole fragment code here

Comment: @ParagChauhan i'm solved it. i'm moved onActivityResult() to parent Activity

Comment: Thank you and late comment sorry

Comment: @bongjaechoe its fine ,our concern is solution any how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your `Parent Activity`

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```